# I want to know how to access the data from a list of objects to get the mean, median, and mode using the library statistics

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, statistics

What I have so far:

```
import statistics
"""This class is what captures and uses the values inputted into the class"""
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def basic_stats(person_list):
    """
    takes a list of person objects,
     and returns, mean, median, and mode of their ages
    """

    mean = statistics.mean(person_list.age)
    median = statistics.median(person_list.age)
    mode = statistics.mode(person_list.age)
    tuple = (mean, median, mode)

    return tuple
```

and I am testing it as such:

```
# test case:
p1 = Person("Kyoungmin", 73)
p2 = Person("Mercedes", 24)
p3 = Person("Avanika", 48)
p4 = Person("Marta", 24)
person_list = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
print(basic_stats(person_list))  # should print a tuple of three values
```

its intended to take the age from each object p1,..,p4 and calculate the mean, median, and mode from this information.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see is that you need to turn your list of people into a list of ages:

```
def basic_stats(person_list):
    ages = [person.age for person in person_list]

    mean = statistics.mean(ages)
    median = statistics.median(ages)
    mode = statistics.mode(ages)
    tuple = (mean, median, mode)

    return tuple
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to just write a new list with the age values using list comprehension: new_list= [i.age for i in person_list]